# Why does package.lock file requirements section change when the related package stays the same?

Tags: npm, dependencies, semantic-versioning, package-lock.json

How is this `package-lock.json` change possible:

Before:

```
...
    "chokidar": {
      "version": "1.7.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar/-/chokidar-1.7.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-eY5ol3gVHIB2tLNg5e3SjNortGg=",
      "requires": {
        "anymatch": "1.3.2",
        "async-each": "1.0.3",
        "glob-parent": "2.0.0",
        "inherits": "2.0.4",
        "is-binary-path": "1.0.1",
        "is-glob": "2.0.1",
        "path-is-absolute": "1.0.1",
        "readdirp": "2.2.1"
      }
    },
...
```

After:

```
...
    "chokidar": {
      "version": "1.7.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar/-/chokidar-1.7.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-eY5ol3gVHIB2tLNg5e3SjNortGg=",
      "requires": {
        "anymatch": "^1.3.0",
        "async-each": "^1.0.0",
        "fsevents": "^1.0.0",
        "glob-parent": "^2.0.0",
        "inherits": "^2.0.1",
        "is-binary-path": "^1.0.0",
        "is-glob": "^2.0.0",
        "path-is-absolute": "^1.0.0",
        "readdirp": "^2.0.0"
      }
    },
...
```

This happens inside a docker container -- so platform is not an issue. integrity field matches -- so WTF. Required versions change (that could be `npm audit`) but fsevents as a requirement is **new** while the package has not changed. 
Can anybody give me a clue?

Comment: Are you sure you have the before and after listed in the correct order?

Comment: Yes.. I checked this many times over.. Also -- notice that even if I did have it the wrong way around -- the resolved url is identical, the integrity fingerprint is identical and still, the requirements are very different

Comment: Did the version of NPM change?

Comment: Nope.. The npm version have changed _since_ then but same npm version across those two `package-lock` files.

Even if it were different -- still does not make sense a requirement appears out of nowhere for the same version of a dependency.

Comment: You should file a bug: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues

Comment: Why would a `package-lock.json` file have version ranges listed in it?  Unless perhaps it was unable to resolve a set of packages for `chokidar-1.7.0`?  My limited knowledge of NPM, tells me that tool records a set of package-version strings that will satisfy the dependent's requirements at that moment in time.  It does this by checking its own local cache and querying the remote feeds you've configured it for.

Comment: The whole point of the tool is to record the exact versions resolved, such that you can later use that lock file to reproduce an earlier build.  It can't possibly do that, if it finds version ranges in the lock file.

Comment: Great point -- there should not be version ranges in a package-lock file.